# Are all objects created before method calls?

Tags: ruby

Here is some code from the RubyMonk tutorial:

```
class Shoe
  def initialize(toes = 1)
    @toes = toes
  end

  puts "1 inside the class: #{defined?(@toes).inspect}"

  def i_can_haz_toes
    puts "2 inside the instance: #{defined?(@toes).inspect}"
  end
end

class Foot
  def initialize(toes = 5)
    @toes = toes
  end

  puts "3 inside the class: #{defined?(@toes).inspect}"

  def i_can_haz_toes
    puts "4 inside the instance: #{defined?(@toes).inspect}"
  end
end

samurai_boot = Shoe.new(2)
samurai_boot.i_can_haz_toes

left = Foot.new
left.i_can_haz_toes

puts "5 in the `main` class: #{defined?(@toes).inspect}"
```

Here is the output:

```
1 inside the class: nil
3 inside the class: nil
2 inside the instance: "instance-variable"
4 inside the instance: "instance-variable"
5 in the `main` class: nil
```

I don't get the order of the output. In the code, object Shoe is created first, then a method is called on it, and only after this is object Foot created. To me, this should have printed

```
1 inside the class: nil
2 inside the instance: "instance-variable"
3 inside the class: nil
4 inside the instance: "instance-variable"
5 in the `main` class: nil
```

Seems Shoe and Foot were both created before any methods were called on either of them. How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, the `class` keyword opens a class and executes ruby code in the scope of that class.

```
class Object
  puts 'Hello'
end
puts 'World'
```

prints

```
Hello
World
```

Creating a class if not exist is merely a side effect.

By the way, the `def` syntax is just an expression that defines a method and returns its name.